# Как сделать вот эти косые линии и чтобы они всегда одним концом упирались в эту часть прицела, а другим в конец бордера заголовка?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать вот эти косые линии и чтобы они всегда одним концом упирались в эту часть прицела, а другим в конец бордера заголовка?

Есть svg (четверть прицела) и заголовок с бордером. Нужно чтобы линия была между бордером заголовка и центром svg.

Пробовал подгонять линией svg ( <line id="line" x1="149" y1="21" x2="120" y2="90" и т.д.), но там только фиксированные значения, при изменении разрешения всё ломается.

https://github.com/bessonniy11/mouseenter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: svg + js (пересчитывать значения) или пересмотреть верстку : например  текст как часть svg, текст и линия - имеют один родительский div который позиционируется к прицелу. Без примера кода фантазия может привести куда угодно, Прочитайте пожалуйста [ask] и [mre]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.